# Struggling to take a React webpage screenshot

Tags: node.js, reactjs, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I want to take a screenshot of a React application webpage which opens at the following url when I run my application locally :
http://localhost:3400/someapi/email

I have unsuccessfully tried to take the screenshot with phantom (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom)

It failed because phantomJS has no support for ES6. 
Also, I could not inject polyfill core.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) to 
the phantom js page with async await, as I am using Node v.6.9.1.

Any other alternatives/npm packages which makes this process of taking screenshot of a react webpage easy for me?

**Any detailed example would be much appreciated!

Comment: PhantomJS is not being developed anymore and hasn't been for some time now. Try using Puppeteer instead: https://pptr.dev

Comment: Works great!! Thanks a ton, saved my life.